# Redirecting page when entering it PHP

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

Hello Im trying to add a default url when entering a website for example:

From this

```
http://example.com
```

To this

```
http://example.com/defaultUrl/
```

I have tried doing this with JavaScript in the beggining of the page but it just causes an infinite loop and I dont think it's very secure. Is where anyway to do this with PHP? I HAVE TRIED the header() function TOO but it just causes an infinite loop of redirects.

Answer (score 0):

Within your `index.php` file add this code at the top:

```
header('Location: /defaultUrl/', true, 301);
exit;
```

Comment: I put this at the very beginning of my index.php and it gives me the 'Too many redirects' error :/

Comment: That would suggest that /defaultUrl/ resolves to /index.php under the hood. Have you set up any rewrites at server level?